# Action View naming conventions for templates in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

For some reason I could only find one word template names in all the examples that I have seen, is there any convention behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is derived from method naming convention. Since a view is rendered in response to an action, it shares action's name. Since action is a method, and...

> - Use `snake_case` for symbols, methods and variables. [[source, Ruby Style Guide]](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars)

You should write multi-word action names `like_this`.